# How to add a custom validation rule in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I would like to add custom validations rules on my Laravel Controller:

- The container exists in the database
- The logged user is owner of the resource

So I wrote this:

```
public function update($id, Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|unique:stock.containers|max:255'
    ]);

    $container = Container::find($id);

    if(!$container)
    {
        $validator->errors()->add('id', 'Not a valid resource');
    }

    if($container->owner_id != user_id())
    {
        $validator->errors()->add('owner_id', 'Not owner of this resource');
    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);  //i'm not getting any
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `$validator->errors()` or even `$validator->addMessageBag()` does not work. I noticed `$validator->fails()` clears the error messages and adding an error will not make the validation to fail.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: [This](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules) is the correct way.

Comment: Well, then how do you apply this rule. The rule does not know the `id` of the resource and the rule does not apply to any value in the `request`...

Comment: You are using a wrong approach I believe. Because you can use the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-exists) on the validator to make sure that the resource exists, but then you need to use a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies) which will authorize the user for using the resource.

Comment: @nakov, Yes I can use the exists, but I don't have the `$id` of my resource, so I cannot check if it exists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use `after`:

```
public function update($id, Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|unique:stock.containers|max:255'
    ]);

    $validator->after(function($validator) use($id) {
        $container = Container::find($id);

        if(!$container)
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('id', 'Not a valid resource');
        }

        if($container->owner_id != user_id())
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('owner_id', 'Not owner of this resource');
        }
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);  //i'm not getting any
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggested solution is not working. laravel does not come in `$validator->after(function($validator) use($id) {` function. I have added a `echo 'test';exit;` before `$container = Container::find($id);` line but nothing is working. Any suggestion will be welcomed.